# UITableView contentOffset when status bar at 40 points

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Displaying our UITableView we are generally seeing:

```
self.tableView.contentOffset.y: -64.0
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height: 44.0 
UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height: 20.0
```

However when on a phone call or using the Hotspot the status bar height is 40 points while the offset remains at -64 (and the nav bar stays at 44).

Why in this case isn't the offset -84 to accommodate the extra height of the status bar?

We are using these values to position an element above the UITableView.

Comment: Why would the offset be different? The table view's frame origin doesn't change.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what the offset represents.  I understood it to be the area of the table view which is not displayed or is effectively hidden.  And as the height of the status bar increases it would effectively mean that a larger amount of the table view is not displayed.  I have been using this post as my source of how the offset works https://www.objc.io/issues/3-views/scroll-view/